# GitFlow - who tags master branch

Tags: git, continuous-integration

I want to setup a new Project with Git and some CI tools. 
I also want to follow the GitFlow strategy.

As I understand it right I have the follow situation:

1. I have a Build Step that builds my code
2. I have a Test Step that tests my code
3. I deploy my code to the production

If I use the gitflow principle:

1. When do I have to tag the master branch? Before I build the code (but what if the tests fail, do I manually remove the Tag)?
2. How Tags the Master branch? The developer or the CI Tool?